# stm32g491cet6 ADC interruption and Hal_Delay not working

Tags: ide, stm32, delay, adc, stm32cubeide

I have a number of issues with stm32g491cet6.

When using the ADC interrupt, it remains in an infinite loop. When using the HAL_Delay () function, an infinite loop also results.

The code is simple and runs on the application board with stm32f103 but not on stm32g491cet6 (two separate projects of course).

The PWM work good.
Any ideas?

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

   HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  if (HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Configuration Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */


       HAL_ADC_Start_IT (&hadc1);
       HAL_Delay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc){

HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4);

}
```

Comment: Could you please strip down your code to be minimal?

Comment: it looks like you use CubeMX? If yes, please check, if Interrupts are enabled in the "NVIC" tab of the ADC settings. Furthermore: i have never used ADC in IT mode, but I am pretty sure, that >>HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback<< is used for ADC in DMA mode only. As far as I read about the IT-Mode, the interrupt should be catched in stm32nxx_it.c, not as you expect in the DMA callback function.

Comment: yes, the interrupt is on. The function is good. Like I said, the same program runs on stm32f103. Thanks.